# Is it possible to use the same database for two Django projects containing different models?

Tags: django, django-migrations

We planned for two Django projects. Say, Project-1  contains Model A and B. and  Other Project-2 contains Model C and D. But I am afraid if it possible or not as I am new in the Django World. Your suggestions  would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sure you can, so long as they don't use the same database table names. However, it would be better to separate the projects into two databases since some of Django's core apps such as the migration framework uses a (nearly) hard-coded table name.

Comment: So long as each project used a unique name for the database `NAME` setting and your database supports multiple databases/schemas it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You should add all models in both Django projects but the models that you want to not managed or ignored set the managed=False in Meta class of that model.

Project-1 `models.py`

```
*** another models

class ModelC(models.Model):
    ***
    class Meta:
        managed = False

class ModelD(models.Model):
    ***
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

same this for the project2. see more information you need [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/options/#managed).

---

Edited
Project-2 `models.py`

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    ***
    class Meta:
        managed = False

class ModelB(models.Model):
    ***
    class Meta:
        managed = False

*** another models
```

Comment: This would mean neither project would be able to use Django's migrations, which is probably not what you'd want.

Comment: @AKX i just edited the answer, what i mean, that models A, B will be managed in Proejct-1 and models C and D could be managed in Project-2.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. I have another issue. What about if two project plan to apply individual custom User(AbstractUser) for example p1_user and p2_user in same  database?